# AttributeError: module 'camelot' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Tags: python, python-camelot

I am trying to extract tables from pdf using camelot and I get this attribute error. Could you please help?

```py
import camelot
import pandas as pd
pdf = camelot.read_pdf("Gordian.pdf")
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 pdf = camelot.read_pdf("Gordian.pdf")
>
> AttributeError: module 'camelot' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Comment: Please read https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/118 and https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/145.

If you don't find a solution, post the output of the command dir(camelot)

Comment: you may have probably installed camleot instead of camelot-py

Answer (score 18):

**NOTE** : **If you are using virtual environment activate environment before do this things.**

I have already faced this error.There is a no bug in your code.The problem is with camelot installation.

1 remove installed camelot version

2 install again using this command. There is a multiple ways to install camelot. Please try it one by one

- `pip install camelot-py`
- `pip install camelot-py[cv]`
- `pip install camelot-py[all]`

3 run your code >> i have attached sample code here

```
import camelot

data = camelot.read_pdf("test_file.pdf", pages='all')
print(data)
```

Comment: It will work on python editor eg: pycharm

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately. So commenting so future users can assess.

Answer (score 7):

Try this: `import camelot.io as camelot`
That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

please check if you have java installed on you machine, go to your terminal and run "java -version", if you do not have you won't be able to read pdf using Camelot or tabula,

once you have installed java, install tabula-py using the command
`pip install tabula-py`.

```
from tabula.io import read_pdf
tables = read_pdf('file.pdf')  # substitute your file name
```

Answer (score 4):

I abandoned trying to get camelot to work in Jupiter Notebooks to read tables & instead installed the following:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install tabula-py tabulate

from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate


pdf_path = (
    Path.home()
    / "my_pdf.pdf"
)
df = read_pdf(str(pdf_path), pages=1)
df[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link with full installation steps:
https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#using-pip

After you install

```
pip install camelot-py[cv]
```

Write this:

```py
import camelot.io as camelot
```

Comment: I think that most user do `pip install camelot` which installs something else entirely: https://pypi.org/project/Camelot/

Answer (score 0):

pip uninstall camelot
pip uninstall camelot-py
pip install camelot-py[cv]

## install ghostscript app from internet

! apt install ghostscript python3-tk
pip install ghostscript

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of the answers here are all correct. However, the confusion lies in the name of the library. There are two Camelot libraries in pycharm.

If you are looking for PDF table extraction, it is called `camelot-py` NOT `Camelot`

and then add `import camelot.io as camelot`

If you confused the two libraries, importing camelot.io will not work.

If it still give you an error. Try removing `Camelot` from the project interpreter. That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

When downloading the library please pay attention to where it is downloaded. Because the library you downloaded may have been saved in another Python version

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can elaborate how to pay this kind of attention, what would you expect ti find, annd how it should be fixed.