# can't read pdf files by using camelot

Tags: python-3.x, python-camelot, python-pdfreader

import camelot

from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

file = "foo.pdf"

tables = camelot.read_pdf(file)

print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)

tables = camelot.read_pdf(file)

print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)

print(tables[0].df)

i can't read the pdf file here.Also it is showing it as attribute error as
AttributeError: module 'camelot' has no attribute 'read_pdf'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'camelot' has no attribute 'read\_pdf'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376583/attributeerror-module-camelot-has-no-attribute-read-pdf)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.